# Problem sending Android data to PHP script

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an application that will involve interaction with a MySQL database whereby the posted data is handled using PHP.

From an Android app, i send HttpRequests to a PHP file [at localhost], which creates a connection to a MySQL database and drops some data in a table.

The problem that I am having is that I have installed XAMPP [Apache server, MySQL] but when I start the Apache service, and start the Android application it doesn't fetch any data.

What are the best requirements that will help me get out of this mess so that I may connect my Android app to a MySQL database then do some scripting using PHP?

Comment: You're not supplying enough information. Please include all relevant source code here, beginning from your Android application (i.e. where it sends its data). We also need to know how your PHP script looks like.

Answer (score -1):

I have just do the same thing. You should upload your database and php script to a shared host. There are alot of free hosting out there.
[www.byethost.com](http://www.byethost.com)
[www.oni.cc](http://www.oni.cc)

for example. Have fun.
PS: If you dont want to use a shared host, so make sure that your device is connected to your computer's private network. The easy way is use wifi in the same subnet as the server. Otherwise, your device is just dont know where is "localhost" because it's not public.

Comment: Why should he need to go to a shared host? Your answer doesn't even remotely help because there's no additional information about what is going on.

Comment: The thing is going on, as I see, is his device dont know where is "localhost" it cannot get fetch data, right? So we have to find a way for the Android device to recognize it. By the way, the question is clear, what is the requirement to connect Android to MySQL. I've just give a way to do it.

Comment: We don't know anything. It could be that the Android app doesn't send any data at all. We also don't know if he uses a real device or an emulator -- in the former case there would be no `localhost` and we would need to know if the device can even pint the computer or reach the web server, or if it isn't blocked by a firewall. We also don't know if the PHP script correctly receives data, neither do we know about how communication is established (i.e. asynchronously or via GET requests), et cetera et cetera.

Comment: Ok, it's my bad. I dont cover all possible situations. Sorry for that.

Comment: hey, don't worry... Let's just wait what information we can get :)